# Передача значения из Form1 в UserConstol C#

Tags: c#, form, usercontrol

Задача:

Есть два элемента - Form1 и userControl1.
В Form1 есть textBox1 с каким то значением.

В userControl нужно взять это значение из textBox1 в форме Form1 и записать в переменную save_path (string save_path)

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ для новичков, без хендлеров, делегатов, ссылок и тому подобных вещей (как вы поняли, что способов много):

В Form1:

```
public void ButtonClick()
{
  UserControl UC = new UserControl(textBox1.Text);
  UC.Show();
}
```

В UserControl, в первой функции с иницизализацией в аргумент запишите `string Value.`

Условно

```
string save_path = "";
public UserControl(string Value)
{
    InitializaComponent();
    save_path = Value;
}
```

P.S. это не самый прогрессивный метод, не самый замороченный, но весьма простой

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: К сожалению не работает :(

Comment: как вы создаете екземпляр своего контрла, отредактируйте вопрос и вставьте туда свой код, где происходит инициализации экземпляра контрола и где контролу (внутри) уже надо получить переменную

Comment: Уже решил, ваш ответ все же помог, просто я не до конца разобрался)

Comment: рад быть полезным